# SearchView filter with RecyclerView

Tags: android, adapter, searchview, android-recyclerview

I have tried to implement a SearchView with suggestions (filter) in Fragment, but I have not managed it. I tried almost every tutorial but nothing worked for me. I would appreciate any help. Thank you

XML 
...

```
    <!--appBar layout-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <!--searchView layout-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_clear_white_18dp"
            app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
            app:queryHint="@string/search_contact"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!-- recycler view-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false);

        searchView = (SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        fabButton = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fab_button);

        //recycler view
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        contacts = SugarRecord.listAll(Contact.class);
        contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity(), contacts);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // TODO: setFilter

                return true;
            }
        });

        return view;
```

Adapter

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ContactVH> {

    List<Contact> mContact;
    List<Contact> mContactFilter;

    Context mContext;

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contact) {
        this.mContact = contact;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_contact, parent, false);
        ContactVH viewHolder = new ContactVH(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactVH holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(mContact.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContact.size();
    }

    class ContactVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.contact_name)
        TextView name;

        public ContactVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This tutorial is very helpful for me ...https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/03/searchview-with-recyclerview.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create class which extends **Filter**

```
class YourFilterClass extends Filter {

private List<Contact> contactList;
private List<Contact> filteredContactList;
private ContactsAdapter adapter;

    public YourFilterClass(List<Contact> contactList, ContactsAdapter adapter) {
     this.adapter = adapter;
     this.contactList = contactList;
     this.filteredContactList = new ArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    filteredContactList.clear();
    final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

    //here you need to add proper items do filteredContactList
     for (final Contact item : contactList) {
            if (item.getName().toLowerCase().trim().contains("pattern")) { 
                filteredContactList.add(item);
            }
        }

        results.values = filteredContactList;
        results.count = filteredContactList.size();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        adapter.setList(filteredContactList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

}

And then you can add this **Filter** to yours **ContactsAdapter**.

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ContactVH> {

List<Contact> mContact;
List<Contact> mContactFilter;
YourFilterClass filter;

Context mContext;

public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contact) {
    this.mContact = contact;
    this.mContactFilter = contact;
    this.mContext = context;
    filter = new YourFilterClass(mContact, this);
}

@Override
public ContactVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_contact, parent, false);
    ContactVH viewHolder = new ContactVH(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactVH holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(mContactFilter.get(position).getName());
}
// set adapter filtered list
public void setList(List<Contact> list) {
    this.mContactFilter = list;
}
//call when you want to filter
public void filterList(String text) {
    filter.filter(text);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mContactFilter.size();
}

class ContactVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.contact_name)
    TextView name;

    public ContactVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thank a lot! So I have to call filterList on OnQueryTextListener() ?

Comment: Yes you can call it in onQueryTextChange()

Comment: OK, it does not work now, I have a look at it. One more question. What exactly does this: 

for (final Contact item : contactList) {
            if (item.getName().toLowerCase().trim().contains("pattern")) {
                filteredContactList.add(item);
            }
        }
I mean ....contains("this word here")

Comment: Here you should add all items which you want to your filteredList. This is just an example. If "this word here" will be some part of item name then this expreasion will be true

Comment: So how do I known that there are letters from SearchView? For example if I write "a" it will show all names which start with "a.."

Comment: You should use "constraint" from method performFiltering ()

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you very much, I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @R.Adasiewicz really nice , but in which package i can find the filter class ?

Answer (score 2):

[image: searchview filter woth recyclerview]

In your adapter class implement filterable and overide it's method.

```
    @Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            if(charSequence == null | charSequence.length() == 0){
                filterResults.count = getUserModelListFiltered.size();
                filterResults.values = getUserModelListFiltered;

            }else{
                String searchChr = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

                List<UserModel> resultData = new ArrayList<>();

                for(UserModel userModel: getUserModelListFiltered){
                    if(userModel.getUserName().toLowerCase().contains(searchChr)){
                        resultData.add(userModel);
                    }
                }
                filterResults.count = resultData.size();
                filterResults.values = resultData;

            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

            userModelList = (List<UserModel>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

in your main activity create searchview and listen to onQueryTextChange.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            usersAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });



    return  true;
}
```

full tutorial and source code.
[Recyclerview with search / filter](https://youtu.be/ujKDN_ZtGHQ?sub_confirmation=1)

Answer (score 0):

*Try This*

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();

    search(searchView);
}

public static void search(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView) {

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mCategoryAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

**implement Filterable to your Adapter class**

public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements Filterable {

```
private List<Category> categoryList;
private List<Category> mFilteredList;


public CategoryAdapter(List<Category> categoryList) {

    this.categoryList = categoryList;
    this.mFilteredList = categoryList;
}

@Override
public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.category_card, parent, false);

    return new CategoryViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Category category = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.catname.setText(category.getCatName());
        holder.items.setText(category.getCatItems()+" Items");


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFilteredList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                mFilteredList = categoryList;
            } else {

                List<Category> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Category category : categoryList) {

                    if (category.getCatName().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || String.valueOf(category.getId()).contains(charString)) {

                        filteredList.add(category);
                    }
                }

                mFilteredList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            mFilteredList = (List<Category>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView catname, items;
    public ImageView imgView;

    public CategoryViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        catname = view.findViewById(R.id.categorycard_cate_name);
        items = view.findViewById(R.id.categorycard_lbl_cat_items);

    }
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    mFilteredList.remove(position);
    // notify the item removed by position
    // to perform recycler view delete animations
    // NOTE: don't call notifyDataSetChanged()
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void restoreItem(Category category, int position) {
    mFilteredList.add(position, category);
    // notify item added by position
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchView addCustomerPageSearchView = findViewById(R.id.addCustomerPageSearchView);
    addCustomerPageSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            searchResult(query);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            searchResult(newText);

            return true;
        }
    });


    private void searchResult(String query)
    {
    String q = query.toLowerCase();
    List<ModelContacts> updatedList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ModelContacts modelContacts : contactList)
    {
        if(modelContacts.getName().toLowerCase().contains(q))
        {
            updatedList.add(modelContacts);
        }
    }

    adapter = new ContactAdapter(getApplicationContext(), updatedList);
    contactListRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late, but maybe it can help someone. If you're trying to search without providing a custom filter, do so with the adapter's getFilter override. But if your search uses custom logic options, do it in setQueryTextListener in the onQueryTextChange section.