# Android searchview filter in recyclerview pagingDataAdapter with Paging3 is not updating the data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-search, android-paging-3

I am trying to search a value from database with the search filter. but not updating the searched values in adapter.

Note: loading the data using **Paging3 library**.

```
  private val mDiffer: AsyncListDiffer<Data?> = AsyncListDiffer(this, DataComparator)

 object DataComparator: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Data>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Data, newItem: Data): Boolean {
          
            return oldItem.mobileNo == newItem.mobileNo
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Data, newItem: Data): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }


    fun submitList(list: List<Data?>?)
    {
        mDiffer.submitList(list)

    }
 override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence?, filterResults: FilterResults)
            {
                submitList(filterResults.values as MutableList<Data>)
              

              
                if (filterResults.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
```

iam getting the searched values in **inmDiffer.submitList(list)** method. but values are not added in adapter.

kindly help me to achieve this.

links referred https://howtodoandroid.com/pagination-with-paging-3-android/
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098390/searchview-filter-with-recyclerview)
thanks in advance

Comment: I think 1st you need to clear the Adapter (old values) and then load values may it works

Comment: Where is your query submit functionality?

Comment: Is it actual implementation in your project?